# check if length in rtattr even

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tlv

In my kernel code I need to parse a number of TLV-like attributes `rtattr`. Is there a way to validate that length is correct, i.e. it has to be even. Is there a macro for this?

Answer (score 0):

In BER-TLV data, L-value can be dynamically changed length. In case in 1-st byte bit 8 is 1 is meant that the L-length param is used several bytes. The rest of 1-st, byte masked with 0x7F, will show you the amount of bytes used for Length definition.

For sample `0x820102` will describe: the 1-st byte bit 8 set to 1 and the Length part with dynamic length the rest of 1-st byte which is `0x02` show the amount of bytes used for length. The `0x0102` the hexadecimal Length itself equal 258 bytes.